# Can I change a menu after I logged in, in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I've got this wordpress site. And i've made two menu's. One which is supposed to be shown when a user isn't logged in, and one for when a user is logged in. And i'm talking about a login to the website it self, not the dashboard.

How do I make the menu's change, from the one I have where I am not logged in, to the one where I am?

I've tried adding the following code to the functions.php page, but it isn't working.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
$args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else {
$args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
}
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

I'm not sure where to look next, and I can't find any solutions on google. Hope someone can help me out!

I've also made sure i got the session_start(); at the top of every .php page.

Comment: You may have more luck with [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) than checking the session status. We'd also be able to help you more if you could describe "isn't working" a little better. What exactly do you expect to happen with your code, and what is happening that's different from that?

Comment: Oh right! Well I want the menu to change. So when a person is logged in, the menu should change to the logged in one, and to the logged out one if not. And it just stays at the logged out one. How does the is_user_logged_in work when I'm logging in using a database?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're logging in using a database, exactly?

Comment: I got a database with username and passwords, and if the login matches I start a session. So in that way logging in using db.

Answer (score 1):

You can make 2 different menus and use a simple if else :

```
<?php
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'registered-menu' ) );
   } else {
      wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'visitor-menu' ) );
   }
?>
```

Comment: Well as far as I know, that if checks if the user is logged in to the dashboard. That's not what I want to check. I want itito check it to my login.php file and change the menu for the common registred user.